# Second fundamental form for surfaces (extrinsic curvature)

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, general-relativity

I'm trying to understand the [Gibbons–Hawking term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbons%E2%80%93Hawking%E2%80%93York_boundary_term). There appears $K$- a trace of the second fundamental form, as they say.

As far as I know, the second fundamental form is the following thing:
Suppose we have two manifolds $M$ and $N$, and $M$ is a surface in $N$ ($M \hookrightarrow N$). $g$ is a metrics on $N$, so $f^{*}g$ (pullback) is a metrics on $M$. Let $\rho$ to be a projection $T_{x}N \rightarrow T_{x}M$. Then $\nabla^M_{y}X=\rho(\nabla^N_{y}X)$ is a Levi-Civita connection on $M$ . Superscripts $M$ and $N$ are correspond to manifolds and $X$,$Y$ $\in \Gamma(TM)$. Then we have 
$\nabla^N_{y}X - \nabla^M_{y}X=(id-\rho)\nabla^N_{y}X=B(X,Y)$. $B(X,Y)$ is called a second fundamental form.

But all physicists I know write $K=h^{ab}K_{ab}=h^{ab}\nabla_{a}n_{b}$, where $h$ is induced metrics, and $n$ is a **normal vector**. (for example, check this [link](http://www.physics.ntua.gr/cosmo11/Naxos2011/Tuesday%20Talks/Becker.pdf), slide number $5$, page $14$, where he introduced GH term for action. Or you can find other examples with ease by yourself).

So I don't understand how $n$ have appeared in definition of $K$. Can you explain it to me? Maybe I'm mistaken in my definition of second fundamental form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming $M$ is a hypersurface here, since you refer only to a single normal.

The first definition is the *normal component* of the derivative, and can be written $B(X,Y) = g(\nabla_Y X, n)$. (To match your definition strictly you must multiply this again by the vector field $n$; but since the normal bundle is one-dimensional this is useless information.)

The product rule lets us write this as $$B(X,Y) = \nabla_Y g(X,n) - g(X,\nabla_Y n),$$ but this first term vanishes because $X$ is tangent to $M$ while $n$ is orthogonal. Thus $B(X,Y) = -g(X,\nabla_Y n)$, or in index notation $B_{ij} = - \nabla_j n_i$. This is what you have up to a sign - some people choose the opposite sign convention so that they can simply write $B = \nabla n$.

Comment: @Anthone Carapetis Thank you for an explanation! Physicists never explain anything ;D Finally  I get the correspondence <3

Comment: @Anthony Carapetis thx for your answer!